# java mysql callableStatement setString with no quotation mark

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connection

I want some method of `CallableStatement` class to generate a query of named parameters with no quotation mark.

```
String query = "update table ? ";
CallableSatement cs = connection.prepareCall(query);
cs.setString(1,"table_name");
cs.updateQuery();
```

the generated query is something like this:

```
 update table 'table_name'
```

while I want this:

```
update table table_name
```

without the quotation mark!
  please help!

Comment: Is impossible.
Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072929/incorrect-syntax-near-p0-exception-when-create-and-drop-login-in-mssql/18072974#18072974): different statement, same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't do this. Parameters placeholders can only be used for values, not for object names like the name of a table. You will need to construct the query dynamically by concatenating the table name to the update statement. Just make sure to guard yourself against SQL injection.

Also note that `update table <whatever>` is not valid SQL.

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
cs.setString(1,"'table_name'");
```

Java will just do a literal substitution, so if you want the quotes, you better put them in!

Comment: it will be generate this:  '\' table_name\' '

Comment: Those backslashes don't make sense

Comment: dude! I want bare string

Comment: Now I will actually learn something about `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: Java won't do anything, it is the individual driver implementation that handles the parameter placeholder. Most drivers won't even do substitution, but simply prepare the statement as is and use a variable descriptor for the parameters. Using placeholders is only allowed for values, not for object names.

Comment: Like I said, I am utterly unqualified to answer this question. I just thought I'd have a go.