# Incorrect syntax near '@P0'. exception when create and drop Login in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm trying to create a Login and drop it using using Microsoft JDBC Driver.

`CREATE LOGIN ? WITH PASSWORD = 'password'`

and

`DROP LOGIN ?`

But I'm getting following exception in both cases.

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:332)
    at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.core.internal.manager.MSSQLRSSManager.attachUserToDatabase(MSSQLRSSManager.java:512)
    ... 57 more
```

I found similar questions in SO, but couldn't find an exact solution.

Please advice.

Thanks,
Bhathiya

[update]

Here is my code snippet.

```
String sql = "CREATE LOGIN ? WITH PASSWORD = 'abc'";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, qualifiedUsername);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: How are you executing the query in your code ? Can you post it ?

Comment: Question updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use ? in `drop login` statement (like in drop table, you cant write `drop table ?` - I'm facing the same problem just in that days!), you have to build statement with string concatenation in old fashion way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What about the create one?

Comment: I think is the same things. You have to build your sql as: `String sql = "CREATE LOGIN " + qualifiedUsername + " WITH PASSWORD = 'abc'";`

Answer (score 4):

Using '?' is how your client code accepts parameters for statements. Most DDL statements like CREATE/ALTER/DROP do **not** accept parameters. When in doubt, you can always check the documentation of the statement, like [CREATE LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

The solution is to build the statement dynamically and replace the login name in the statement itself, but be warned that doing so is subject to SQL injection problems and you must ensure your input is properly sanitized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was following documentation always. But I can't find this information anywhere. (i.e. which accept params and which don't)

Comment: @Bhathiya You can only use parameters in place of (literal) values or variables. An objectname (like a loginname or table name) cannot be parametrized.