# createSQLQuery with parameter in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to run this:

```
..
String modelTableName = (model == TableModelType.RING) ? "RING_PLAYERS" : "TOURNY_PLAYERS";

List<Object[]> results = dbs.createSQLQuery("SELECT group_level, COUNT(group_level) FROM :modelTableName WHERE game_id=:gameId GROUP BY group_level")
                .addScalar("group_level", Hibernate.INTEGER)
                .addScalar("COUNT(group_level)", Hibernate.LONG)
                .setString("modelTableName", getModelTableName())
                .setInteger("gameId", getGameId())
                .list();
```

It gives an exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

If I write "RING_PLAYERS" instead of ":tableModelName" then it WORKS!

What am I doing wrong with this parameter?

Thank you.

Comment: `getModelTableName()` does this method gets your value as expected?

Comment: Yes it does.
It would be interesting to put hard-coded the string instead of the function just to check if the createSQLQuery works well.

Comment: Allright , did you tried in staticway if your code style is suitable for this situation , or string initialization and use it in setString method?

Comment: My final conclusion is that it's not possible to parameterize the "FROM" clause of the SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer, you can not inject the table name: [Table name as parameter in HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576864/table-name-as-parameter-in-hql)

You may have to construct it as:

```
List<Object[]> results = dbs.createSQLQuery("SELECT group_level, COUNT(group_level) FROM " + getModelTableName() + " WHERE game_id=:gameId GROUP BY group_level")
                .addScalar("group_level", Hibernate.INTEGER)
                .addScalar("COUNT(group_level)", Hibernate.LONG)
                .setInteger("gameId", getGameId())
                .list();
```